# How to create multiple vendor modules with splitChunks

Tags: webpack, webpack-splitchunks

I have an app with an `admin` and `frontend` module. The admin environment is has a single react-router entry point and I don't care too much about chunking here. The front end needs chunking. Every approach I see uses a node_modules based vendor chunk. How do I make sure that that vendor chunk only contains the front-end related modules,and not the admin ones?

Ideally I would like to be able to filter this through the react-router starting point for admin and frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this easily and in the end just decided to make the jump to Razzle. Other challenges, but at least this works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. set `splitChunks.chunks` to `initial`/`all`.
2. set `{cacheGroup}.test` to the path of `frontend`.
3. finally, disable the default cache group for vendors by setting the [`defaultVendors`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks) to `false`.

Disclaimer: I haven't try it.